# Llibraries used in commercial game software (alternatives to SDL)

Tags: user-interface, audio, graphics, sdl

I was just wondering what software libraries are often used in professional commercial game software? I'm mainly interested in Windows, but Linux software interests me as well.

I've seen a lot of hobby projects / open source projects and the like using SDL, but I imagine very little commercial software uses it.

I know SDL does the following; I'm curious what alternatives are available (my educated guesses in brackets):

Time and Timers (Boost, Windows API)
Sound (DirectX (others??))
Graphics (OpenGL, DirectX)
Networking (DirectX, Berkley sockets)
Threads (Boost, Pthreads, Windows threads)
Event Based Joystick / Mouse / Keyboard Input (Direct X? Windows API?)
GUIs  (C# winforms? Windows API)

Is a lot of this stuff proprietary depending on the company too?

I know there is no one-all-end-all, but I'm just curious about the industry and what are the de facto standards. Any info from experienced people appreciated.

Comment: SDL is used in quite a bit of commercial software. Penumbra, World of Goo, Braid (Linux version), etc. just to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Windows games use DirectX for pretty much everything (rendering, sound, input). OpenGL is used by multi platform games, since it works on Windows, Linux and OSX.
Some big games use engines that can use multiple rendering paths, such as Direct3D, OpenGL, and proprietary stuff for PS3, Wii, etc.